# Is it normal for an LED bulb to become hot to the touch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

Overhead light was flickering.  Opened it up and the old LED bulb in there was hot to the touch-- something I've never experienced with LED bulbs.  This is a pretty old original fixture.  Is there something wrong with the wiring/socket, or is this how an LED bulb goes bad?

The old bulb that got hot is the third photo-- the bulb with fins.  The one currently installed I put in to test but don't want to mess around with it too much if it could be faulty wiring.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't tell if yours is one, but a lot of LED bulbs say "not for use in fully enclosed fixtures" or similar. They are prone to overheating when there's nowhere for the heat to go. They don't get nearly as hot as incandescents, but they also can't _tolerate_ nearly as much heat as incandescents can.

Comment: The bulb has 120V written on it, while the socket has 250V written on it. What voltage is your supply?

Comment: @AaronF That's just the maximum rating for the socket.

Comment: @Herohtar And it means that the same socket model can be used in US and EU products.

Comment: There's also some 208/240 V industrial lighting in the US/North America. Streetlights are the most common example, as to reduce the voltage drop and increase efficiency over long cable runs.

Comment: Btw - if you don't want to change the entire lamp, yet make it led-friendly, look for round LED plates, like [this one that I quickly found on google](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32965974214.html). This is what similarly looking LED ceiling panels use. The LEDs are more spread out and the heat dissipates better. You'll need to match the size and the voltage, and probably get a bit creative with fixing it in place, but I think it should be doable.

Comment: In my recollection in fixtures like this the glass bowl does not fit closely to the metal bezel (has a gap at the top) so hot air can escape. Does yours have a gap? It would even better if there were holes in the bottom to allow ambient air to flow in, but I don't recall ever seeing that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These bulbs will get hot to touch and the domed fixtures have always contributed to the heat because there's no where for the heat to go, unlike ceiling fan light fixtures and lamps with shades. When the wiring has been compromised, it's usually burnt or darkened exiting the sockets so this looks OK. Flickering is a premature sign of failure.

Comment: +1, many bulb lights (and similar) come with an insulated pad to protect the ceiling side from the bulb heat. On some it is often reflective so you get some heat protection and additional light output. As answered, your _bulb_ will probably die before the _socket_ because (right now) the fixture was likely designed for much more heating from an incandescent bulb.

Comment: @StephanSamuel  Good point. This even adds more heat to degrade the electronics in the LED bulbs.  I would not recommend removing it though because when you alter the fixture, you void the UL listing.

Answer (score 25):

LEDs generate heat like any electrical device. That's why some have cooling fins. It takes longer and they don't get *as* hot, but they'll still sting skin if they've been on for a while.

Flickering is a common failure mode--the electronic driver is probably getting weak. If the bulb was seated properly it's likely on its way out the door. They last a good long time on average, but not as long as the early marketing led everyone to think.

Comment: The light fixture itself seems like it might retain heat.  Can a different fixture increase an LEDs life span.  Op is worried the wiring might be the cause, but maybe just the design of the fixture could be the cause?

Comment: Well, heat cycle is the primary cause of electronic failure, so sure. That's a very common light fixture design, though, so I'm not inclined to suggest that millions of people should replace them to gain what's probably negligible bulb life.

Comment: I wonder if that design uses fins because it runs a bit hot anyway, either because it's driving high power LEDs, or because it's not great to start with

Comment: @ChrisH The fins were common in early LED models for heat dissipation.  I still have one that gets daily use, certainly got my money's worth out of it.

Comment: ***not as long as the early marketing led everyone to think*** ...exactly.

Comment: Some of the better bulbs (especially ones that included things like fins) will last a long time, like the one that @rtaft has. Compare a name brand to a dollar store item: same light output with possibly a vastly different average life expectancy.

Comment: LED bulbs are, almost universally, very finely calibrated to overdrive their LEDs just enough to cook them prematurely so that they don't vastly outlast what people are used to with incandescents.  And when I say "finely calibrated", I mean they have two resistors of unusual values wired in parallel to provide an overall resistance within a narrow specific range to achieve just the right amount of too-much-voltage.  If you're willing to mess with these bulbs, it's generally not hard to find these resistors and break one, significantly increasing longevity.

Comment: I don't believe spurious stories like that, Atario. Show evidence not just of minimalist engineering but of deliberate sabotage, please, or stop spreading nonsense.

Comment: *Good quality* LED lighting can last practically forever, but capitalism won, and most LED lighting is not good quality. Of course, that is partially the user's responsibility for installing it in a certain type of fixture, not necessarily the bulb itself - this bulb has a lot more cooling fins than the cheap ones do. And good quality LED lighting is not necessarily the type that's designed to plug in where incandescents used to be.

Answer (score 11):

Led bulbs typically fail because their electronics wear out, heat being a prime accelerator of this.

The bulb that was used was not very effective by modern standards at only 66 lm/W.
The same amount of light (485 lm) can be made by a 2.3W bulb today, at 210 lm/W.

That will probably prevent overheating of the electronics of a new bulb in the same fixture.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say "prevent", but "significantly reduce the likelihood". +1 anyway.

Comment: 210 lm/W would be a very good bulb.

Comment: @AndreKR: 210 lm/W is indeed the best I was able to put in my online shopping basket, but it is available

Comment: @AndreKR one of the Gulf state Emirates has mandated LEDs with significantly higher efficiency than commonly used in most of the world, in limited quantities they are available elsewhere if you look for them.  The engineering itself is straightforward; they used several times as many individual LEDs allowing them to be run at lower and more efficient power levels.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight That would be Dubai, and bigclivedotcom did a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klaJqofCsu4) on the subject in 2021.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Even the Dubai lamp has "only" 200 lm/W, the GU5.3 variant even less. They claim significant longer lifetime though.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Dubai bulbs are illegal in California and therefore not officially sold in the US. They don't meet CA Title 20's >90 CRI and dimmability requirements. The Dubai bulbs have high efficacy, but as people learned from CFLs, quality is important if you want people to use them.